# Return Filtered Module in DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to make a filter in certain Module and get the filtered items and loop over them and do some kind of operation.
problem is filtering isn't done , something is wrong as follows :

```
Filter SwTest = includes(attribute "aVerificationStrategy" ,"SwTest") 
Filter Implemented = (attribute "aObjectStatus" < "inReview")
Filter SwTestReqsCASTLE = SwTest && Implemented
Module m = srs_doc
set(m, SwTestReqsCASTLE, accepted , rejected)
filtering on  OR ApplyFiltering(m) , i tried each as don't know difference !
```

so what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer your main question, first allow me to answer your implied question about the difference between "filtering on" and "ApplyFiltering(m)". The difference is that "filtering on" displays the current filter in the module window, meaning that objects are either shown or hidden depending on the filter. "ApplyFiltering(m)" applies the current filter settings to the module explorer (the area to the left of your objects that shows the hierarchy). "filtering on" shows and hides objects and "ApplyFiltering(m)" reflects the status of those objects in the module explorer.

As for why your filters are not being applied, there could be several reasons:

1. It is good practice to turn filtering off before you start setting filters. Add the line "filtering off" before the rest of your code.
2. Your "Implemented" filter is not defined properly. DOORS will see "inReview" as a string, and it will perform a direct comparison with the string value of your "aObjectStatus" attribute in order to determine if an object is accepted or rejected. Is this what you intended?
3. What type of variable is srs_doc? If it's a string then you need to
   call read(), share(), or edit() in order to actually open the
   module. If it is a module variable then that line is correct.
4. I am assuming that "accepted" and "rejected" are integers, but if they are not previously declared then they need to be.
5. Based on the first paragraph in my comment, your last line should read "filtering on"
6. Is the module you want to filter being displayed? I realize this is probably obvious, but I have made this mistake before so I thought I should mention it. A filter cannot be applied on a module that is not currently being displayed.

As a side note, you can compound your SwTest and Implemented filters without creating extra Filter variables as follows:

```
Filter SwTestReqsCASTLE = includes(attribute "aVerificationStrategy", "SwTest") && (attribute "aObjectStatus" < "inReview")
```

I hope some of that helps! Good luck, and let me know if none of the above solves your problem.